# Splitting a line separated list into multiple smaller lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of proxies separated by line. These proxies need to be separate into separate lists with sizes that I choose.

So I want the program to input how many lists of 10, 25, and 50 I need them to be split into, then output the new lists as a text file. The same proxy cannot be present in two separate lists.

This is what I've got so far simply to count the proxies

```
filename = input('Enter a file name: ')
with open(filename) as f:
    line_count = 0
    for line in f:
        line_count += 1

print("Number of proxies: " + str(line_count))
```

Any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and expected output?

Comment: So lets say the file it loads is a text file containing the numbers 1 to 100. I want this split into 5 text files containing 10 numbers each, then 2 text files containing 25 numbers each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a variable sizes try this:

```
def split_list(filename, sizes):
    with open(filename) as f:
        content = f.readlines()

    new_content = []
    start = 0
    for size in sizes:
        stop = start + size
        new_content.append(content[start:stop])
        start += size

    return new_content

splitted_list = split_list('data.txt', [5, 2, 3])

for i, l in enumerate(splitted_list):
    with open('{}.txt'.format(i), 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(l)
```

Given `data.txt` is

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

it will generate three files (as specified in the second argument of the `split_list` function):

`0.txt` with the first `5` lines (the first specified chunk):

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

`1.txt` with the following `2` lines (the second chunk):

```
6
7
```

Finally `2.txt` with the last `3` lines (third chunk):

```
8
9
10
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Here is the code I plan to have before the split function https://pastebin.com/ifSASRxn - how can I make it so the [5, 2, 3] correspond to the pack sizes I choose?

Comment: You are welcome. :). In order to use the function above you just need to provide a list of the chunk sizes you want. In the example it means first five lines, following two lines and following 3 lines. So in your case instead of calculating `packs` as the total count of lines make it as a list of chunk sizes and pass it to `split_list`. Something like: `packs = ([pack10] * 10) + ([pack25] * 25) + ([pack50] * 50) + ([pack100] * 100)`. I am assuming you want the chunks of size `10` to come before the ones of size `25` and so on.

Comment: Hi, I tried that using a text file with 100 numbers, https://pastebin.com/km3PZkez - this is my code. It seems to only work when there's only packs of 10 but otherwise the program spits out text files with only 5 or 2 lines in each of them. And no matter what, 184 text files are made, most of them empty.

Comment: Sorry about that. I wrote the wrong line on my previous comment. It should be `packs =  ([10] * pack10) + ([25] * pack25) + ([50] * pack50) + ([100] * pack100)`.

Comment: Great, thanks again. One last question - how would I make it so instead of the names being 1.txt, 2.txt, etc it'd be 10pack1, 10pack2, 25pack3, 25pack4, etc?

Comment: There is a for loop after the call to `split_lines` where we open files for writing. In that loop just change the string corresponding to the filename. In this case specifically from `with open('{}.txt'.format(i), 'w') as f:` to `with open('{}pack{}'.format(len(l), i), 'w') as f:`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by something like that:

```
def split_list(filename, size)
    new_content = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        for chunk in range(0, len(content), size):
            new_content.append(content[chunk:chunk+size])
```

The code will generate numbers (*range*) from 0 to the length of the file. Using *step* param of *range*, we can increase the starting point by *size* every iteration.

The code will go through the list, and use slicing to get chunks of elements form the list constructing a new one. Those new lists will be the elements of a new list, *new_content*.